# Can not get Json data with Alamofire Swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I try to get json data from web site, however, I can access to json data as the following.

```
   { 
  "product_categories":[ 
     {    
     "id":27,
     "name":"Clothing",
     "slug":"product-categories-1",
     "parent":0,
     "description":"",
     "count":3
   }
  ]
}
```

On the other hand, when I try to get json data as below,

```
   { 
     "product":{ 
     "title":"Night Cream",
     "id":4573,
     "created_at":"2015-08-21T07:54:09Z",
     "updated_at":"2015-08-27T01:37:06Z",
    }

 }
```

there is on jason data response back “[]”

I am using  Alamofire to get data. Here is my code.

```
       Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON {
        (request, response, json, error) in

        if json != nil {


            var jsonObj = JSON(json!)

            if let data = jsonObj["product"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                self.productsAll = data
                self.collectionView!.reloadData()

            }
```

How can I get all of product data. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: In the first case you have been in json array and in the second case case  there is only a dictionary in json, but you're trying to get an array with `jsonObj["product"].arrayValue as [JSON]?` and its empty becouse there is no array type in json. At this case you need to access the data as an ordinary dictionary

Comment: Try this: `if let data = jsonObj["product"] as! [NSDictionary]`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried it already but it is still not working.
Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to cast a json object to a json array, which means your conditional unwrapping will never execute.

replace

```
if let data = jsonObj["product"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
    self.productsAll = data
    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

with

```
if let data = jsonObj["product"].dictionaryObject {
    // since self.productsAll seems to be an array, append the product to the array or rebuild the array before calling self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```